# Restricting Powershell Results/Output

Tags: powershell, active-directory, output, restriction

The following query works fine:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Division -like "PNCC"' -Properties * |
  Select-Object Name, @{name=”MemberOf”;expression={$_.memberof -join “;”}} |
  Export-Csv test.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

However, the customers requirements are to display a specific subset of memberof groups.
How do you restrict the `memberof` groups returned, either by parent OU the groups are in or by group names? The parent OU has 3 Child OUs. Within those 3 Child OU's are the actual AD Groups.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the expression of your calculated property with a filter, e.g. like this:

```
$groups = 'foo', 'bar'

... | Select-Object Name, @{n='MemberOf';e={
  @($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Where-Object {$groups -contains $_.Name}) -join ';'
}} | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Ansgar answer would work, but I think it's creating too much noise and may be optimized a bit. As number of groups should usually be lower than number of users it may be smarter to collect distinguishedNames of groups that should be reported first (with small hack to avoid collecting empty groups):

```
$groupsInOu = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase 'OU=DGG,DC=domain,DC=com' -LDAPFilter '(member=*)' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.DistinguishedName }
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Division -like "PNCC"' -Properties * |
    Select-Object Name, @{name=”MemberOf”;expression={($_.memberof | Where-Object { $groupsInOu -contains $_ }) -join ';' } } |
    Export-Csv test.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Or if you want to filter on a name (or any other property), I would create hashtable with DistinguishedName as a keys and AD object with property (or properties) that you care about as values:

```
$groupsHash = @{}
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter '(member=*)' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $groupsHash.Add($_.DistinguishedName, $_)
    }

Get-ADUser -Filter 'Division -like "PNCC"' -Properties * |
    Select-Object Name, @{name=”MemberOf”;expression={($_.memberof | Where-Object { $groupsHash[$_].Name -match 'someRegex' }) -join ';' } } |
    Export-Csv test.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Also I would be more specific about properties I want to get (`-Properties memberof`) unless you plan to use some other properties in the report too.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you very much! Exactly what I needed.